When connecting to remote debugger, breakpoints won't be hit and dlls not showing in module window
I have a multi project solution that I have deployed to a local server that has both a MVC site and an API service to populate it.  When I try to attach to the w3wp process with the remote debugger, while the Microsoft dlls show up in the module window, none of the solution's dlls are visible.  The breakpoints in the solution also show that they will not be hit.
I've experienced this a few times before and usually deleting the bin, obj, and vs folders then rebuilding have solved the problem but it isn't working this time.
Things that I have verified:

I've deployed the debug build

Just my Code is not selected

My Visual Studio and the Remote Debugger are version 2022


Any ideas as to what my next steps might be?
